# What do I need to do to run JavaScript with VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Newly starting up VSCode, having used Eclipse previously.

I expect to be overwhelmed by the new thing, and am following [this introductory video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-s71n0dHUk), recommended by the VSCode site. At 3:15, having entered some JavaScript code, he presses <kbd>F5</kbd> and the script runs.

My JavaScript script looks like this:

```
console.log("--------------------");
console.log("--------------------");
console.log("--------------------");
console.log("bubbles");
```

That doesn't happens with me. With the relevant editor open, and the tab for the JavaScript script file selected, I press <kbd>F5</kbd>, and another window opens saying "Visual Studio Code - Editing evolved" (i.e. the "Welcome" screen again), and the status bar of the original window turns red. None of this looks good.

What do I need to do to run the JavaScript?